# Sending event values to Google Analytics using Zapier

Tags: google-analytics, automation, crm, zapier

I'm using Close.io as a CRM, I want to be able to create an event on Google Analytics and record the conversion value. The purpose of this is so that I can tie a certain Google Ad to its performance. On Close.io this would be a new Opportunity created. I'm using Zapier to integrate the two platforms and it has a new Beta integration with Google Analytics. I set it up so that when a new Opportunity is created, it creates a measurement on GA with the measurement type "Event Tracking", and the category, action and label similar to the goal I created on GA. However, when I send tests to GA, it's not appearing in my acquisitions report on GA.

There are fields for Customer Client ID and User ID.For customer ID there's a description that says: "This anonymously identifies a particular user, device, or browser instance. Google may ignore repeated identical measurements. The value of this field should be a random UUID (version 4) which you could generate using a Code Step. Defaults to a UUID shared by all Zapier users"

I'm thinking of capturing unique session ID on the form using javascript and filling these fields in to see if it works. Please help with thoughts and feedback. Thanks!